# Java Switch/Case alternative to update a Map

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, optimization, switch-statement

I am trying to figure out if there is a better and cleaner way to implement the following code and replace the switch/case statements. I appreciate your help and comments.

```
class Student {

    public String name;
    public Map<String, String> properties;

}

class MainClass {

    public void doAction(List<Student> students) {

        for (Student student : students) {

            switch (student.name) {
            case "Bob":
                student.properties.put("key1", "value1");
                student.properties.put("key2", "value2");
                break;

            case "Sophie":
                student.properties.put("key3", "value3");
                student.properties.put("key4", "value4");
                break;

            case "Natalie":
                student.properties.put("key5", "value5");
                student.properties.put("key6", "value6");
                break;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What's bad about a `switch`?

Comment: Nothing bad..., just wondering if there is a better/cleaner way.

Comment: This whole thing is weird. If you're trying to create a list of students, then just initialize them with `Map.of()`, don't separate the initialization into different components that will get out of sync and are hard to read.

Comment: No, this is not to initialize a list of students. I am getting a list of students (which already have some values in their property map), and I am going to add some properties based on their names (the case conditions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> studentProperties = new HashMap();
studentProperties.put("Bob", Map.of("key1", "value1", "key2", "value2"));
studentProperties.put("Sophie", Map.of("key3", "value3", "key4", "value4"));
...

for (Student student : students) {
    if(studentProperties.containsKey(student.name)) {
        student.properties.putAll(studentProperties.get(student.name))
    }
}
```

Just because the requirement is to avoid switch. Notice we sacrifice space complexity here by populating all entries beforehand.